Incorrect Bezier curve in Maya
I have implemented Bezier Curve that complies to the mathematical rules, using de casteljau's algorithm. I have tested my implementation with other libraries, such as OpenNURBS, and our results match. However, when I create a bezier curve in maya, using the same control vertices, the curve is incorrect.
Example:
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.curve( d=3, p=[(-1,0,0), (-1,2,0), (0,1,0), (1,2,0), (1,0,0)] )
mc.nurbsCurveToBezier( )

To evaluate the curve, I created a locator and used a motion path constrain and set the U value to 0.5.

When this curve is evaluated for t=0.5, maya returns ( 0.0, 1.5, 0.0 ), whereas the correct answer is { 0 , 1.375 , 0 }.
Am I creating a bezier curve in maya properly? If so, why am I seeing different results?
